# Python: Splitting string to replace a character messes up indexes

Tags: python, string, replace

i'm trying to make a version of the hangman's game.
I setup the word string, replace vowels with + and the rest with - and so on.
The problem comes when i need to replace the chars in the string:
I read many questions regarding python's string replacement and the closest thing to what i need appears to be `string = string[:index] + char + [index+1:]`. The problem is that the index becomes completely random:

Example
Word: `stuck`
Formatted:  `- - + - -`

If i send c:
it finds out that the index is 3 so the string should be string[:3] + char + string[4:]
resulting in `- - + c -`
Instead what happens is :

```
- c + - -
```

Is this string starting from index 2?

Code:

Swapping function

```
def swapChar(position, tstring, char):
    print("/////////")
    print(position)
    print(tstring).       # note 1
    print(char)
    print("////////")
    print(tstring[0 : (position+2)] + " NEWCHAR " + tstring[(position+3):])   # note 2
    first = tstring[:position-1]
    print("First: " + first)
    second = tstring [position+1:]
    print("Second: " + second)
    string = first + char + second    # note 3
    return string
```

Note 1: Printed this info to check whether the values getting to the functions were correct, and indeed they are

```
/////////
3
 - - + - -
c
////////
```

Note 2: Even summing 2 to the indexes results in the wrong position

```
 - -  NEWCHAR  - -
```

Note 3: I also tried to split the splitting, but to no avail.

Moreover sometimes i noticed that selecting a second char might add a position to the string (for example, with stuck, if i input `u`, it may become `- u c + - -` and so on (i got out some words that were like `+ - e m p i r e - + - +` by completing them)).

Either string splitting is made randomly or there is something i'm not getting about how it's done, and i would say the latter is more probable.

Bonus example logs:

```
Chosen Word: ruth
Letter: r
Letter: u
Letter: t
Letter: h
[ MESSAGE ] {{ /device/write }} "h"
Equivalence:  r = h
Equivalence:  u = h
Equivalence:  t = h
Equivalence:  h = h
/////////
3
 - + - -
h
////////
First:  -
Second:  - -
- h - -
```

If you need any other info just ask

Comment: Are you considering that spaces are also characters? The strings seem to have space between all characters, thus they also count when considering the indexes.

Comment: I feel really stoopid right now

Comment: @MiquelEscobar If you want to post it as an answer i will accept it

Comment: Hahhahaha it happens to all of us ;)

Comment: @MiquelEscobar i have been trying to solve this for the last 3 hours and the answer was "spaces" hahahahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you considering that spaces are also characters? The strings seem to have space between all characters, thus they also count when considering the indexes and it messes up your approach.